# GCP VM Autoscaling instances taking longer than expected to spawn based on unacked pub/sub messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, autoscaling

I have an app that does video transcoding & image classification. Right now, it takes about 2-5 minutes per job and I'm scaling my VM's based off how many unacked pubsub messages there are in the queue using the autoscaler metrics.

In production, I have each VM handling two messages so that a single job takes no longer than 10 minutes for a user. But, when my queue starts filling up I'm noticing it takes at least 2-4 minutes for the autoscaler to even kick in. And sometimes they scale in very slowly.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to use the unacked message metric on the auto scaler group to get this to spin up quicker?

At the end of the day I'm looking to scale up VM's quickly based off number of unacked queues. I know I could do this programmatically but I'd rather let GCP handle the complexity.

Any insights?